# Site.getPathPrefix() is Null even when page reference is set

Tags: apex, unit-test, force.com-sites

I am writing a test class for one of my controllers. And in the test class i am setting the current page as given below

```
pagereference pageref1 = new pagereference('/apex/E2E_Screen_2');
        pageref1.getParameters().put('id', Abolish.id);
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef1);
```

Now in the controller I am using the Site.getPathPrefix() to get the value from the URL, but the value that is returned from site.getPathPrefix() is null. I tried to print the URL of the current page using

```
string x = ApexPages.currentPage();
srting y = ApexPages.currentPage().getURL();
```

The value of the URL is displayed correctly. Can anyone please tell me why the site.getPathPrefix() value is null here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods of the Site class (including [getPathPrefix](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm#apex_System_Site_getPathPrefix)) depend on the specific [site](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites) the code is running in. That site definition is separate from the Visualforce and Apex you create and there is no built-in mechanism in in the testing framework to fake running in a site.

So if you are testing some logic that requires there to be a prefix, you can modify the code you are writing the test for to get the prefix from a method:

```
private String getPathPrefix() {
    return Test.isRunningTest() ? 'fakePathPrefix' : Site.getPathPrefix();
}
```

and your test can rely on the fake value.

(This sort of test conditional logic is a last resort.)

Comment: I'll see if I can add the mentioned logic. Thanks!